# Android Toolbar: centrar título

Tags: android

Estou a tentar centrar o titulo da minha `Toolbar` mas não consigo.

Já tentei usar `Theme` (não funcionou) e já tentei no código Java (no entanto no código Java como estou a utilizar a **API 13**, não posso utilizar o `.setTextAligment`). Também já tentei utilizar `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(toolbar.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER)` que também não funcionou.

Já não tenho mais ideias...

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.Title" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Set proper title size -->
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow0"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_main">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/brown"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="70dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMesActual"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/brown"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons"
            android:text="Botão1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonInserir"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons"
            android:text="Botão2"
            android:textColor="@color/brown"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

        <Button
            android:textColor="@color/brown"
            android:id="@+id/buttonMessPassados"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons"
            android:text="Botão3"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/buttons"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonDefinirM"
            android:textColor="@color/brown"
            android:text="Botão4"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableRow android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/textMesActual"
                android:text="Text2:"
                android:textColor="@color/brown"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textMes"
                android:textColor="@color/brown"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/brown"
                android:id="@+id/textDespesas"
                android:text="Text1:"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/textDesp"
                android:textColor="@color/brown"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/textMeta"
                android:text="Text0: "
                android:textColor="@color/brown"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textMetaDef"
                android:textColor="@color/brown"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**toolbar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#fdeec1" android:endColor="#f9d35e"  />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Já tentou setar o seu `style` com o atributo `app:theme`?

Comment: @sicachester, ultimo comentairo pf

Comment: Comente da resposta do sicachester, ou ele não será notificado.

Comment: @bfavaretto comento aqui porque em baixo ao escrever o nome_usuario depois não me aparece

Comment: O sistema remove o @usuario porque ele é desnecessário ali (a resposta é dele, ele é notificado de todos os comentários). Já aqui, como ele não está nesta "conversa" (não comentou), não recebe notificação alguma (nem com `@`). Ver http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/943/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lembre-se que a `Toolbar` é um `ViewGroup`, ou seja, você pode colocar componentes dentro dela sem nenhum problema.

Para colocar um texto no centro, coloque um `TextView` como o atributo `android:gravity="center"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/seuStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Seu titulo"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Apenas um detalhe importante que eu observei em seu layout: utilize o inteiro que está no `AppCompat` chamado `?attr/actionBarSize` para definir o tamanho de sua `Toolbar`. Irá aplicar o tamanho padrão e correto para sua `Toolbar`

Refêrencia: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

@Edit

No seu layout, o `TextView` está como `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` e            `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. Deixe como `match_parent` e irá funcionar

Comment: Já tinha tentado esta solução mas não funciona. Aparece o nome da Aplicaçao e depois o titulo do TextView (da Toolbar), cheguei tambem a tirar o label no manifest, mas não resulta. Também já tentei no Java fazer toolbar.setTitle(null) e só depois fazer um setTitle, mas nada disto funciona :\

Comment: @porthfind você removeu a tag no manifesto ou deixou como "" (vazia)?

Comment: Tinha apagado a label e já vi que era esse o problema, já a coloquei vazia e pelo menos essa parte já está bem, mas o texto continua a aparecer sem ser centrado, será q é de eu ter a Toolbar dentro de umm LinearLayout? Actualizei a pergunta com o layout para ser mais facil.

Comment: @porthfind Pode remover sim, não tem necessidade de colocar o `Toolbar` dentro de outro `ViewGroup`, e também você está dando re-drawn de de background (já que pinta o `LinearLayout`e logo em seguida a sua `Toolbar`)

Comment: Não posso tirar o LinearLayout porque tenho outros componentes, pensava q podia..actualizei a minha pergunta com o layout completo, será q podes ver se ha alguma coisa mal q esteja a impedir centrar o texto?

Comment: @porthfind o que tem no arquivo `toolbar_main` ?

Comment: É para desenhar uma linha branca no fim da toolbar e meter degrade na cor de background. actualizei pergunta com codigo da toolbar_main

Comment: @porthfind editei! Veja se resolve

Comment: Obrigadaaaaa!Funcionou! :D

Comment: @porthfind ótimo! Qualquer dúvida só perguntar

Answer (score 0):

Minha opinião e que você não procure colocar o texto dessa forma pois não vai de acordo com as especificações de espaços e posicionamento definidas **[aqui](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html)**.

Tente sempre seguir as *guidelines* e verá que ira fazer uma app mais facilmente e de alta qualidade